# How to deploy .net package from visual studio to sharepoint developer site?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, deployment

I'm new to sharepoint. My application app part is in sharepoint and web part is hosted in Azure. I have a developer site for this application and code in visual studio. I need to deploy my code into this sharepoint developer site and debug the solution. The URL which was working for the developer site is no more working. Please help me in deploying this code to this sharepoint developer site.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ONjJ.png)

Comment: According to your question, It seems like it is provider hosted app. I would recommend you to refer this link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/steve_fox/2013/02/17/building-your-first-provider-hosted-app-for-sharepoint-using-windows-azure-part-1/

Comment: This link also - https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/sharepoint-provider-hosted-mvc-app-office365-azure/